# Drupal 7 - Adding data in specific content type field

Tags: drupal, installation

Currently I am building an installation profile for Drupal 7.
I make multiple fields and create instances for the fields at a specific content type.

Now I add a new node to the content type but I don't know how to add data into the fields I generated for this content type. This has to happen all in the installation profile so in code and no explanation for Drupal it self.

The node is generated like this:

```
$node          = new stdClass();
$node->title   = 'Test title';
node_save($node);
```

This is not the whole code of course but is just to give you an idea. Currently I add the type, status, uid, title, promote, created, timestamp, sticky, format, language, teaser, body and revision to the $node. Now I want to add my custom field data, anybody has an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like...

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'article';
$node->title = 'Test title';
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
node_object_prepare($node);
// Other properties...

// Single cardinality
$node->field_some_text_field[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'Some value';

// Multiple cardinality
$node->field_some_entity_reference_field[$node->language][]['target_id'] = 123;
$node->field_some_entity_reference_field[$node->language][]['target_id'] = 456;

node_save($node);
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, double checked it, it is not giving any errors but the field is still empty.

Comment: What type of field is it? Each have different column names (the last index in the above arrays) so your mileage will of course vary depending on the types of field you have installed. The above will definitely work, I've used it many hundreds of times

Comment: It is a text field. I made a text field, created an instance of it and now trying to add some text to it, all with the installation profile.

Comment: For a text field it'll be `$node->field_some_text_field[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'Some value';` (obviously replacing `field_some_text_field` with the full name of your field). I would check that your field instance is getting created correctly. Immediately after your code has run, are the `field_data_x` and `field_revision_x` tables in the database (by immediate I mean when you step through with a debugger - waiting until the end of the process is no good as the caches will have been cleared by then)?

Comment: Thank you for the extra info, made some changes replacing code here and there and got it to work! thanks!